# Transfer of Data and Programs to and from VMs on Windows 10 Laptops

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, laptop, virtualbox, file-transfer

I currently have two laptops running Windows 10, one of which is in the process of bricking hence the need. Both laptops have on them VirtualBoxes running versions of Ubuntu, the dying laptop version 18.04 and the new one running version 21.04. The physical laptops are connected with a usb cable for ease of transfer.

What I am hoping to accomplish is the transfer of all data and programs, but not the OS itself, from the old VirtualBox to the new VirtualBox. The first attempt was basic cut-and-paste alone the cable and I ended up with just what I think was a non-functional shredded remains of the old virtualbox in the new laptop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this either at the Windows level or inside the VMs.

1. At Windows level, you could copy the virtual hard disk to the new machine, then mount it on the new VM and copy the files across.
2. At the VM level, if both VMs have access to your WiFi/ local network you could copy the files across using [SCP](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/scp-command-tutorial/), [RSYNC](https://linuxconfig.org/rsync-command-examples) or an [SFTP](https://www.educba.com/what-is-sftp/) program, it would be faster to compress the files first using zip or gzip tar file.